# C Error - Cannot find bounds of current function

Tags: c, function, file, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct dictionary_entry
{
    char *eng;
    char *gr;
} term;

len = 0;
term *terms, *trm;
terms = (term*)malloc(0);
char temp1[50], temp2[50];
trm = (term*)malloc(0);
trm->eng = (char*)malloc(0);
trm->gr = (char*)malloc(0);
FILE *in = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
while(feof(in) == 0)
{
    fscanf(in, "%s %s\n", temp1, temp2);
    trm = (term*)realloc(trm, sizeof(term));
    trm->gr = (char*)realloc(trm, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp1));
    trm->eng = (char*)realloc(trm, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp2));
    strcpy(trm->gr, temp1);
    strcpy(trm->eng, temp2);
    add(&terms, trm, &len);
}
free(trm->eng);
free(trm->gr);
free(trm);
fclose(in);
```

I was trying to read sets of words from my file (eg. word translation) to create a dictionary but as soon as I run the program it crashes. The debugger points me out to the realloc function and an arror message appears. The message is

[debug]Cannot find bounds of current function

and the problem seems to have something to do with the realloc function I'm using. Has anyone faced that problem and if so how can I solve it?

I am using Code::Blocks.

Comment: Check the return value of `malloc`, `realloc`, `fopen` and `fscanf`, every time - always! And please read [this about `feof`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Harris, AgapwIesu this is just part of the program I just forgot to include the main() function here. The only problem is with the realloc() function

Answer (score 1):

You are not reallocating the correct struct fields with this

```
trm->gr = (char*)realloc(trm, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp1));
trm->eng = (char*)realloc(trm, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp2));
```

I suggest it should be

```
trm->gr = (char*)realloc(trm->gr, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp1));
trm->eng = (char*)realloc(trm->eng, sizeof(char) * strlen(temp2));
```

I notice you are using `strlen` to resize, so you perhaps need `+1` for a string terminator too, which (also simplifying) would be

```
trm->gr = realloc(trm->gr, strlen(temp1) + 1);
trm->eng = realloc(trm->eng, strlen(temp2) + 1);
```

But you should always check the return values from functions too.

Comment: I corrected it but there is still the same error appearing when I try to debug.

Comment: *"The only problem is with the realloc() function"* don't you believe it. If you don't know what is causing the error, you don't know what is relevant. That's why it is recommended to post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)